# Filtering specific values on json array and create another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

How can i create another array by filtering one json array and include just the values pairs of a specific key?

Example (Filtering Value Pairs of Number Keys):

Array:

`````
{ Name: 'abcd', Number: '1234' },
{ Name: 'efgh', Number: '5678' }
]````

Result Array:


````var filteredarray = ['1234','5678'];````

Thanks!
`````

Comment: Minimalist answer: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp

Gonna need more details on your question, or at least an attempt to help you out.

Comment: Use map. const array2 = array1.map(function(item) { return item.Number })

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
const a = [
 { Name: 'abcd', Number: '1234' },
 { Name: 'efgh', Number: '5678' }
]

function getNumbers(){
  return a.map(item => item.Number);
}

getNumbers();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! And how can i console.log the resulted array?

Comment: Just simply console.log(getNumbers());

Comment: Great, it works! Im glad.